# Determining the characters of an irrep of $D_4 \times D_8$

Tags: permutations, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters, dihedral-groups

I am using [Linear Representations of Finite Groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387901906) by Jean-Pierre Serre as my reference for this discussion. I would like to use the ideas from the book to determine the character of an irrep of the product of two dihedral groups, $D_4 \times D_8$.

Section 3.2 introduces *Product of two groups*. It is defined as follows.

> Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two groups, and let $G_1 \times G_2$ be their
>   products, that is, the set of pairs $(s_1, s_2)$, with $s_1 \in G_1$
>   and $s_2 \in G_2$.

So, if $(s_1, s_2), (t_1, t_2) \in G_1 \times G_2$, $(s_1, s_2) \cdot (t_1, t_2) = (s_1 t_1, s_2 t_2) \in G_1 \times G_2$.

Let's take our example $D_4 \times D_8$  in consideration. Here, $D_n$ is the dihedral group of order $2 n$. According to Serre, the order of $D_4 \times D_8$ would be $8 \cdot 16 = 128$.

The irreps of a dihedral group $D_n$ of order $2 n$ is given below.

The total number of irreducible representations for $D_n$ is as follows. When $n$ is even, the total number is $\frac{n-2}{2} + 4 = \frac{n}{2} + 3$. When $n$ is odd, it is $\frac{n-1}{2} + 2 = \frac{n+3}{2}$. The one dimensional representations are:

When $n$ is even:

1. The trivial representation, sending all group elements to the $1 \times 1$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1\end{pmatrix}$.
2. The representation, sending all elements in $\langle x \rangle$ to $\begin{pmatrix}1\end{pmatrix}$ and all elements outside $\langle x \rangle$ to $\begin{pmatrix}-1\end{pmatrix}$.
3. The representation, sending all elements in $\langle x^2, y \rangle$ to $\begin{pmatrix}1\end{pmatrix}$ and $x$ to $\begin{pmatrix}-1\end{pmatrix}$.
4. The representation, sending all elements in $\langle x^2, x y \rangle$ to $\begin{pmatrix}1\end{pmatrix}$ and $x$ to $\begin{pmatrix}-1\end{pmatrix}$.

When $n$ is odd:

1. The trivial representation, sending all group elements to the $1 \times 1$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1\end{pmatrix}$.
2. The representation, sending all elements in $\langle x \rangle$ to $\begin{pmatrix}1\end{pmatrix}$ and all elements outside $\langle x \rangle$ to $\begin{pmatrix}-1\end{pmatrix}$.

   The $k$-th two dimensional irreducible representations for the general group elements.

\begin{align}
x \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{n}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{n}}
\end{pmatrix}
\nonumber\\
x^l \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k l}{n}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k l}{n}}
\end{pmatrix}
\nonumber\\
y \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\nonumber\\
x^l y \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
0&e^{\frac{2 \pi i k l}{n}}\\
e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k l}{n}}&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Let's take the case of $x \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{n}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{n}}
\end{pmatrix}$ for both $D_4$ and $D_8$. Let the $x$ be $x_4$ for $D_4$, and $x_8$ for $D_8$. So,

$$x_4 \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$x_8 \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}
\end{pmatrix}$$.

Now, according to Serre, the linear representation of the element $(x_4, x_8) \in D_4 \times D_8$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}
\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}
\end{pmatrix}$.

According to Theorem $10$ from the same section of Serre, as both $\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}
\end{pmatrix}$ are irreducible for $D_4$ and $D_8$ respectively, $\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}
\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}
\end{pmatrix}$ is irreducible for $D_4 \times D_8$.

Now, we will simplify it.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}
\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}
\end{pmatrix}\\
= \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 e^{\frac{3 i k \pi }{4}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & e^{\frac{i k \pi }{4}} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{1}{4} i k \pi } & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\frac{1}{4} (-3) i k \pi } \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Serre also gave a relation for the character of product groups. It is given below.

$$
\chi(x_4 \cdot x_8) = \chi(x_4) \cdot \chi(x_8)
$$

I would like to test this relation for our example.

**Right hand side:**
$$
\chi(x_4) \cdot \chi(x_8)\\
= Tr(\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}
\end{pmatrix}) \cdot Tr(\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}&0\\
0&e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}}
\end{pmatrix}) \\
= (e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}} + e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{4}}) \cdot (e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}} + e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{8}})\\
= \left(e^{-\frac{1}{4} i \pi  k}+e^{\frac{i \pi  k}{4}}\right) \left(e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  k}+e^{\frac{i \pi  k}{2}}\right)\\
= e^{-\frac{1}{4} i \pi  k}+e^{\frac{i \pi  k}{4}}+e^{\frac{1}{4} (-3) i \pi  k}+e^{\frac{3 i \pi  k}{4}}\\
= Tr(\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 e^{\frac{3 i k \pi }{4}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & e^{\frac{i k \pi }{4}} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{1}{4} i k \pi } & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\frac{1}{4} (-3) i k \pi } \\
\end{array}\right))\\
\text{ = Left hand side}
$$

So, it satisfies Serre's relation.

So, that's how I can determine the characters of a product group from those of the multiplicand groups.

Right?